# How to get the id of a object in Django database

Tags: django, django-models, django-urls

I was watching the new Boston Django tutorials. I know they are older, but he explains them well. I’m having trouble with one thing though.

He made a url

```
url[r’(?P<album_id)[0-9]+]
```

I know in Django 2.0 it’s a better way to do this. That’s not the question

His view looks like

```
def details(request,alblum_id):
   return HttpResponse("<h2>The detail for the album ID:" + str(album_id) + "</h2>")
```

My question is how does Django know to get the id of the object from album_id if he never declared it. He just typed in a random variable?

is the "_id" part important for Django ? and that's how it knows the get the id of the database reference?

I understand i need to look at the view, I'm just confused on how Django knows to actually get the ID of the database reference. in the view it looks exactly like what i typed above. he just passed album_id beside request inside the parameters. I am still confused on how Django knows that "album_id" means go find the id of the database object. is that built in ?

link : [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mWofrhTwGWQ&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBlmzzFcLgDhKTTfNLfX1IK&index=12][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view that is specified on the URL line takes the id most likely as a parameter  then use that to look up in the database.

Essentially you need to look at the view to understand what he is doing.

Comment: I understand i need to look at the view, im just confused on how django knows to actually get the ID of the database reference. in the view it looks exactly like what i typed above. he just passed album_id beside request inside the parameters. I am still confused on how django knows that "album_id" means go find the id of the database object. is that built in ?

Comment: It’s not built in. Could you include the entire view? You only have the first line.

Comment: It does not have to be album_id - it can be junk_id - as long as it is used consistently between urls.py and views.py. How you use it inside the view function will determine what it really is. It probably will have something like Album.objects.get(pk=junk_id)

Comment: That’s only the definition of the function. Is there more to it?

Comment: i edited it to exactly how he has it. i also included the link so you can check it out if you want to.

Comment: You haven’t gotten to the part in the tutorial where he changes the view to look up in the database. Essentially he is showing you how you can pass a parameter from the url into your view. If you are having problems It looks like you are missing an ending `>` and there is some misspelling in you url as well.